# How to Get Data Dropdown From Static Dropdown Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

How to Get Data by id or other value From Static Dropdown?
This My View  :

```
        <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">ACTIVE</option>
            <option value="2">INACTIVE</option>
        </select>

        <!--- GET DATA FROM DB WHERE STATUS DROPDOWN --> 
        <select name="result" id="result">
          <option selected="selected" value="">ALL</option>
        </select>
```

My Model :

```
function get($status){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('people', array('status' => $status));
    return $query;
}
```

My Controller :

```
function getresult(){
    $status= $this->input->post('status',TRUE);
    $data = $this->people_model->get($status)->result();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and My Ajax :
[image]

I tried This but no Working Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should get the value of `id` instead of `status` in your `controller function` because that's what you're sending via ajax-

```
function getresult(){
    $status= $this->input->post('id',TRUE);
    $data = $this->people_model->get($status)->result();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

See if this works for you, everything else seems fine to me.

Comment: That's weird. Everything else seems fine to me, I even made a demo and it's working for me. The only thing I can say at this point is to check the path(`url`) of the controller function `getresult()` and name of the model `people_model`, also make sure that you've loaded `people_model` before calling it. See if it helps.

Comment: ops, my bad i got mistake in writing code.. Thank you very much sir.. You Save My Day

Comment: Happy to help. :)